# Erlang invalid guard expression

Tags: erlang

I was trying to write a program that counts up to the largest binary multiple. (A binary multiple of a number, e.g. **N**, is a multiple of the original number and is only made of the digits `0` and `1`.)

However, the expression `lists:max(hd(io_lib:format("~b", [N]))) < 50` throws illegal guard expression error. I know that this was due to calling a function not in [the allowed functions](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-sequences) of the guard sequences, but I don't really know how to avoid this error.

Can somebody explain how to avoid this error?

```erlang
% X: Multiple to be checked
% N: The accumulator
countup(X, N) -> % io:write([X, N]),
    if
        lists:max(hd(io_lib:format("~b", [N]))) < 50 ->
            N;
        true ->
            countup(X, N + X)
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` instead of an `if`:

```
countup(X, N) -> % io:write([X, N]),
    case lists:max(hd(io_lib:format("~b", [N]))) < 50 of
        true ->
            N;
        false ->
            countup(X, N + X)
    end.
```

Or alternatively:

```
countup(X, N) -> % io:write([X, N]),
    case lists:max(hd(io_lib:format("~b", [N]))) of
        Max when Max < 50 ->
            N;
        _ ->
            countup(X, N + X)
    end.
```

In general, `if` is rarely used in Erlang.  One of the most common uses for it is checking which range a value falls into:

```
if X < 10 ->
        small;
   X >= 10, X < 20 ->
        medium;
   X >= 20 ->
        large
end
```

But in almost all other cases, a `case` will be more appropriate.

---

You can use `integer_to_list(N)` instead of `hd(io_lib:format("~b", [N]))`.  `io_lib:format` is guaranteed to return an "iolist" (a nested list of lists and strings), but the specific form of the result is not guaranteed, so your code might break in a future Erlang version if the implementation of `io_lib:format` changes.